# Is there a good way to OAuth2 authenticate immediately?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

When using Google OAuth2 to authenticate, using a Google API, the actual authentication is deferred to a point where you actually make a request of some kind. But if you want to authenticate at any time (without necessarily needing to make an API call), for example when the user clicks an Authenticate-button, how is the preferred way to accomplish this? Should I just call some API method that I really don't care about, just to be able to get sent to the Google webpage where I get the code?

EDIT: This is concerning an installed desktop application.